# Flipping headers on even and odd pages with fandyhdr doesn't work

Tags: r, knitr, pandoc

When using the fancyhdr package in Rmarkdown the header does not flip as code would expect. I have always author on the left and page number on the right. What's wrong?

This is my Rmarkdown file:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output:
  pdf_document:
    toc: no
header-includes:
- \usepackage{fancyhdr}
- \pagestyle{fancy}
- \fancyhead[LO,RE]{Author's Name$:$ Title}
- \fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}
- \fancyfoot[CE,CO]{} <!-- to prevent native page numbering -->
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```
\newpage
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
\newpage
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
\newpage
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
\newpage
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
````

And here as suggested the captured latex code:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{ifxetex,ifluatex}
\usepackage{fixltx2e} % provides \textsubscript
\ifnum 0\ifxetex 1\fi\ifluatex 1\fi=0 % if pdftex
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\else % if luatex or xelatex
  \ifxetex
    \usepackage{mathspec}
  \else
    \usepackage{fontspec}
  \fi
  \defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX,Scale=MatchLowercase}
\fi
% use upquote if available, for straight quotes in verbatim environments
\IfFileExists{upquote.sty}{\usepackage{upquote}}{}
% use microtype if available
\IfFileExists{microtype.sty}{%
\usepackage{microtype}
\UseMicrotypeSet[protrusion]{basicmath} % disable protrusion for tt fonts
}{}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{unicode=true,
            pdftitle={Untitled},
            pdfborder={0 0 0},
            breaklinks=true}
\urlstyle{same}  % don't use monospace font for urls
\usepackage{graphicx,grffile}
\makeatletter
\def\maxwidth{\ifdim\Gin@nat@width>\linewidth\linewidth\else\Gin@nat@width\fi}
\def\maxheight{\ifdim\Gin@nat@height>\textheight\textheight\else\Gin@nat@height\fi}
\makeatother
% Scale images if necessary, so that they will not overflow the page
% margins by default, and it is still possible to overwrite the defaults
% using explicit options in \includegraphics[width, height, ...]{}
\setkeys{Gin}{width=\maxwidth,height=\maxheight,keepaspectratio}
\IfFileExists{parskip.sty}{%
\usepackage{parskip}
}{% else
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{6pt plus 2pt minus 1pt}
}
\setlength{\emergencystretch}{3em}  % prevent overfull lines
\providecommand{\tightlist}{%
  \setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}
% Redefines (sub)paragraphs to behave more like sections
\ifx\paragraph\undefined\else
\let\oldparagraph\paragraph
\renewcommand{\paragraph}[1]{\oldparagraph{#1}\mbox{}}
\fi
\ifx\subparagraph\undefined\else
\let\oldsubparagraph\subparagraph
\renewcommand{\subparagraph}[1]{\oldsubparagraph{#1}\mbox{}}
\fi

%%% Use protect on footnotes to avoid problems with footnotes in titles
\let\rmarkdownfootnote\footnote%
\def\footnote{\protect\rmarkdownfootnote}

%%% Change title format to be more compact
\usepackage{titling}

% Create subtitle command for use in maketitle
\newcommand{\subtitle}[1]{
  \posttitle{
    \begin{center}\large#1\end{center}
    }
}

\setlength{\droptitle}{-2em}
  \title{Untitled}
  \pretitle{\vspace{\droptitle}\centering\huge}
  \posttitle{\par}
  \author{}
  \preauthor{}\postauthor{}
  \date{}
  \predate{}\postdate{}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\fancyfoot[CE,CO]{}
\fancyhead[LO,RE]{Author's Name$:$ Title}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\textbackslash{}documentclass{[}twoside{]}\{xyz\}

\newpage

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. \newpage
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. \newpage
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. \newpage
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.


\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please help us (and also you) and add a minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)), that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: @Bobyandbob thanks, I included the complete Rmarkdown code.

Comment: you haven't shown which documentclass you are using but many default to `oneside` in which case only the odd page head is used, so you would need `\documentclass[twoside]{whatever-you-are-using}`

Comment: ok, then where do you suggest inserting `\documentclass[twoside]{oneside}`(assume) ?

Comment: Your document already starts with a `\documentclass{xyz}` declaration, where xyz may be book, report, or whatever. Try `\documentclass[twoside]{xyz}` instead.

Comment: thanks, tried it with `\documentclass[twoside]{xyz}` just before the first `\newpage` but no change

Comment: @michael-palmer Would you, therefore, assume a bug of the fancyhdr package?

Comment: The `\documentclass` declaration occurs only ONCE - it should normally be the very first line of the entire file. And also, the `xyz` was NOT to be taken literally - it was a stand-in for book, report or some such. I only now notice that you are using LaTeX not directly but as a back-end for Rmarkdown. Can you capture the LaTeX code that Rmarkdown generates? There must be some way to tell Rmarkdown to use the `twoside` option with the `\documentclass` command.

Comment: @michael-palmer Okay, I've added the captured latex code to my question.

Comment: I doubt very much it is a bug of `fandyhdr`. It is not the package's fault what your pre-processor does. Alternating headers/footers etc. work just fine with the package in all my documents and in lots and lots and lots of other people's.

Comment: Off-topic: the generated code loads `hyperref` too early. You probably also run the risk of spurious spaces (possibly). Why is the colon in the header in maths mode for goodness sake? All your pages are right-hand side, so only the `R` headers/footers will have any influence.  `\textbackslash{}documentclass{[}twoside{]}\{xyz\}` ??? This will typeset `\documentclass[twoside]{xyz}` in your document. Don't you see this in the content right after the title? You need to have, in the existing `\documentclass` line at the top `[twoside]` added.

Comment: @cfr Thanks for your valuable insights. Unfortunately they're greek to me since pandoc/knitr creates the obviously annoying LaTeX code. I added fancyhdr to my Rmarkdown according to [Rosanna](https://rosannavanhespenresearch.wordpress.com/2016/03/30/writing-your-thesis-with-r-markdown-5-the-thesis-layout/) and [Tom](http://texblog.org/2007/11/07/headerfooter-in-latex-with-fancyhdr/). In social sciences we find Rmarkdown a great tool for dealing with R analysis output and paper text matters in one program. However, sometimes tweaking is needed, and this is what actually brought me to LaTeX.

Comment: The thing is that to get good results, you need to understand what the code produced does so that you *can* tweak it and so that you can, hopefully configure the tool to produce output which needs less tweaking. You need to start by reading a basic introduction to LaTeX. Otherwise, you'll just end up frustrated. If you don't have the basics, a code clean-up is just a sticking plaster - it isn't really going to help you, even if you think that's what you need. You need to be *able* to write a document in LaTeX directly. You don't have to write your actual documents that way.

Comment: That is, you need to take a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11/what-are-good-learning-resources-for-a-latex-beginner?s=1|0.0000 and follow-up with a good resource which appeals. (If one doesn't make sense, try another. People differ in what works for them.) Avoid the top-rated answer, though. The wikibook is unreliable at best and crap at worst. (Persistent souls have been trying to improve it, but that's just because people insist on using it, so any reduction in its crappiness is good.)

Comment: @cfr You're absolutely right. Anyway thank you for the link concerning LaTeX introductions and your related hints, I already spent some time looking for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the

```
classoption: twoside
```

to your document front-matter settings. Since R Markdown loads [`geometry`](//ctan.org/pkg/geometry), you can also use

```
geometry: twoside
```

Comment: Short and sweet! Due to `geometry` producing an unwanted margin I used `classoption`.